# How can I give two different herf to ankle tag based in if-else

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a `<td>` in my html code that contains `<a>`. I want to give `href` to that anchor tag based on if-else statment.
for example:  `<td>` if `var=1` then `<a herf="1"></a>` else `<a herf="2"></a> 
</td>`. Any ideas how can I do that please?

Comment: Please describe that you want to implement using jquery or php ??

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with PHP.

```
<td>
  <?php if($var == 1) { ?>
     <a href="url1"></a>
  <?php }else if($var == 2){ ?>
     <a href="url2"></a>
  <?php } else { ?>
     <a href="url3"></a>
  <?php } ?>
</td>
```

Comment: I tried this , but it did not work it will work if I only have if statment once I include else the page will stop working

Comment: @sara you can add as many else if ladders as your requirement. I have edited my answer.

Comment: If there are more than two cases you are better off using a Switch to select the URL and then complete the HTML in one go.

Answer (score 0):

It's too much easy then you are thinking,
in php you can do that in following way-

```
<?php 
    $var=1;
?>  
<td>
    <a href="<?php if($var==1) echo "link1"; else echo "link2"; ?>" >Your Link Name</a>
</td>
```

There are more way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that in the following way if you only have few conditions:

```
<a href="<?php echo ($var == 1)? 'link1': 'link2'?>">This is the link by conditions</a>
```

Comment: Works well if there is only ever 2 links which the OP has indicated is the case.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do this so these are just a couple more suggestions.

In all cases `$var` needs it's value to be checked (validated) that it is within the expected valid range.

This is procedural. Method 1 of n.

```
<?php
// Procedural method
// =================
// Determine the link to use dependant upon value of $var
// for testing set $var here
$var = 1;
// $url amd $link_name is always being set to something
switch ($var){
    case 1:
        $url = 'link1';
        $link_name = 'link1';
        break;
    case 2:
        $url = 'link2';
        $link_name = 'link2';
        break;
    // Can add in as many links as you like.
    default:
        $url = '#';
        $link_name = 'Invalid Link';
}
?>
<!-- Create the link -->
<td>
    <a href="<?= $url; ?>"><?= $link_name; ?></a>
</td>
```

This is procedural. Method 2 of n.

```
<?php
$var = 1; // Used for debugging
// If $var is an integer it can be used to index into an array

    $url_array = array(
        array('url' => 'link1','link_name' => 'link1'),
        array('url' => 'link2','link_name' => 'link2'),
        array('url' => 'link3','link_name' => 'link3')
    );

    // Need to check $var is in between 1 and the maximum link count
    $url_entry = $url_array[$var - 1]; // offset by 1 as arrays begin at index = 0
?>
<!-- Create the link -->
<td>
    <a href="<?= $url_entry['url']; ?>"><?= $url_entry['link_name']; ?></a>
</td>
```

The idea here is to determine the link values to be used outside of the HTML (business logic) and then create the HTML (The View) with the required values.

You could take this even further but hopefully this gives you something to think upon.
Have fun.